# Adding objects to array NSXMlParser no data

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to make a XML-parser that saves data from YR.no-API. The parser should add data to these two datastructures. My problem is when i try to add a WeatherTimeData object to my array in WeatherData, it seems like the objects doesnt get added, the following count always give me zero

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"time"])
        {

    [self.weatherdata.timedata addObject:currentWeatherTimeData];
        NSLog(@"amount of objects in timedata-array %d", [[self.weatherdata timedata] count]);
}
```

These are my two data-structures, i alloc weatherData in the following method

```
-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    _weatherdata    = [[WeatherData alloc] init];
    NSURL *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData  *data   = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser          = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;
}
```

Do i have to alloc the array inside of the weatherdata object?

WeatherData.h

```
@interface WeatherData : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *town;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *country;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *timedata;
@end
```

WeatherData.m

```
@implementation WeatherData
@synthesize town = _town;
@synthesize country = _country;
@synthesize timedata = _timedata;
@end
```

WeatherTimeData.h

```
@interface WeatherTimeData : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSDate *startTime;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSDate *endTime;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *iconSymbol;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *windDirection;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *windSpeed;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *temprature;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *preassure;
@end
```

WeatherTimeData.m

```
@implementation WeatherTimeData
@synthesize startTime = _startTime;
@synthesize endTime = _endTime;
@synthesize iconSymbol = _iconSymbol;
@synthesize windDirection = _windDirection;
@synthesize windSpeed = _windSPeed;
@synthesize temprature = _temprature;
@synthesize preassure = _preassure;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of problem is classically because the object hasn't been allocated, and given Objective-C allows messages to be sent to `nil` the programmer doesn't notice.

I think it would be nice to be able to provide a runtime environment variable where such events are logged to stdout...

I would suspect that `[WeatherTimeData init]` isn't creating `timedata` and that's because you haven't provided an implementation for it; just using `@sythensize` isn't enough to create the objects.

Comment: Alright, so i have to write my own init method that allocates memory for this object?